# How to resizing an image with caption while maintaining its aspect ratio

Tags: html, css

I want to display an image that has a caption beneath it. If the user resizes the browser, the image will resize while maintaining its aspect ratio. The width of the image must not exceed its normal width. You can scale down but not scale up beyond its actual size. The image width must also not exceed 500px and the height must not exceed 800px. As you resize the image, the caption's width must align with the image's left and right sides. Here is what I got:

[Working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Deepview/vy6h0rdj/2/)

Code:

```css
.furlHtmlCont {
    max-width: 600px;
    max-height: 800px;
    display: inline-block;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px #c0c0c0;
    border-left: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    border-right: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}

.furlHtmlFooter {
    display: table-caption;
    caption-side: bottom;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}

.furlHtmlImg {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 300px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="furlHtmlCont">
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column">
    <img class="furlHtmlImg" src="http://dhr7l999iqsnw.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/Two_Male_Giraffes_Fighting_600.jpg">
    <div class="furlHtmlFooter">
      <div class="furlHtmlTitle">Caption goes here</div>
      <div class="furlHtmlDesc">Long description goes here. It should wrap at the image's right edge even as the user resizes the image.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem I am having is that the image is exceeding its normal width and getting stretched.

UPDATE:

Although I accepted the answer below, it in fact does NOT work. The height must be limited to 800px.

Comment: You need to crop that image; right now it's has more height than width. You could put a div around the image and overflow: hidden the rest or do the cropping on the back end in your template.

Comment: Cropping is not allowed.

Comment: You are fighting the mathematical law of proportion. Your image will always be distorted unless it's the correct proportion to start with.

Comment: If I can resize the image and keep its aspect ratio the same using javascript, then it can almost certainly be done using css.

Comment: Can you show that example please?

Comment: Sorry, I understand what you wanted now. The image can keep it's height, rather than having to fit the horizontal container it's currently in.

Answer (score 0):

```
.furlHtmlCont {
    max-width: 600px;
    max-height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px #c0c0c0;
    border-left: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    border-right: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    text-align:justify;
}

.furlHtmlFooter {
    display: table-caption;
    caption-side: bottom;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}

.furlHtmlImg {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    object-fit: scale-down;
}
```

change the css as above.
And let me know if it is what you wanted..

Comment: The image still stretches as you resize the browser although less stretching.

Comment: Changed two lines in css . Try it now and see if it works

Comment: You cannot set max-width: 533px;

Comment: yeah got it.Thank you for the question I got the answer and you too :-)

Comment: why cannot i set max-width to 533px. i saw the original pic and the dimension is 533x800

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.

**CSS:**

```
.furlHtmlCont {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    max-height: 800px;
    display: inline-block;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px #c0c0c0;
    border-left: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    border-right: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}

.furlHtmlFooter {
    display: table-caption;
    caption-side: bottom;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}

.furlHtmlImg {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**JSFiddle:** [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yfy2d4qj/1/)

Comment: Almost. If you change max-height from 800px to 400px, the height does not change.

Comment: @AndroidDev Then the image will not be proportional, the container is resizing fine if you want to show half of the image then add `overflow:hidden` but I'd suggest to preserve the dimensions

Comment: The image's aspect ratio must remain the same always and no cropping is allowed.

Comment: I think this seems to fit the what you're asking and it's not cropping the image code is resizing it.

Comment: @AndroidDev Based on you `max-height:400px` with max-width set to 500px, the container is not proportional, If you want the image to fit inside this, then you would need to stretch/change the proportions, which will make the image look ugly. I'd suggest adjusting your other container elements so that they will work well with the current CSS

Comment: Also you said and quote +The image width must also not exceed 500px and the height must not exceed 800px_. So according the above code it does do what you as

Comment: Correction. Your solution does work. I might have mixed up testing your code with the other solutions listed above. Thanks a million!

Comment: @NarenMurali You're welcome I only back people up when I know it's right and working yours did and good answer too.

Comment: I gave it a go here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VzdeRj which assumes the image can't be cropped.

Comment: Although I accepted your answer, it in fact does not work. The height must not exceed 800px.

Comment: @AndroidDev If there is a better answer then you should change it, you should choose the best answer, so that people who view your answer for reference, get the best solution!

Answer (score 0):

Here we go!

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 800px;
  height: 100%;
}

.image-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="http://dhr7l999iqsnw.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/Two_Male_Giraffes_Fighting_600.jpg">
    <div>
      <div>Caption goes here</div>
      <div>Long description goes here. It should wrap at the image's right edge even as the user resizes the image.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Almost. If you change the image container's max-height from 800px to 400px, the height does not get smaller.

Comment: @AndroidDev: After so many tries, finally i found a solution. Now you can resize the `width` or `height` of browser to see the effect. You can also change the `max-width` and `max-height` of `.container` . The image will be fit. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions listed were able to constrain the height to some maximum value. Here's the solution (I also decided to limit the height to a maximum of 400px instead of 800px):

Html:

```
<div class="furlHtmlCont">
    <div style="display: table;">
        <img class="furlHtmlImg">
        <div class="furlHtmlFooter">
            <div class="furlHtmlTitle">Caption goes here</div>
            <div class="furlHtmlDesc">This is where the long description goes and its with should not exceed the width of the image. No clipping either.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.furlHtmlCont {
        max-width: 600px;
        display: inline-block;
        box-shadow: 0 0 8px #c0c0c0;
        border-left: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
        border-right: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    }

    .furlHtmlFooter {
        display: table-caption;
        caption-side: bottom;
        padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    }

    .furlHtmlImg {
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 400px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Deepview/vy6h0rdj/5/

Answer (score -1):

You should have an image of the exact width and height placed there. Every time for the image you can't specify the width and height because that would stretch and distort the image, so put the image in right size to function correctly.